# Удобное расположение файлов для использования

Tags: c#, файлы

В общем... у меня есть прога, к которой нужно прилагать много дополнительных текстовых файлов. Как удобнее сделать так, чтобы пользователь на другом компе не задумывался об переносе вручную этих файлов, чтобы куда бы он не поместил прогу, в каком бы каталоге она не была, всё чётко работало...

Во внутреннем каталоге программы не располагаю файлы потому что ругается компилятор, нужен полный адрес файла. У кого какие идеи, кто и как решал (или решил бы) этот вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для программы Windows Forms можно прописать названия файлов и каталогов в конфиг файл приложения `App.config`, привожу пример для файла `todos.json`

```
<appSettings>
<add key="FileName"
     value="todos.json"/>
</appSettings>
```

тогда при старте приложения можно выполнить след. метод

```
private string GetFileName()
{   
    //читаем имя файла из конфиг.файла
    string postfix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"];
    //получаем текущий директорий в котором работает приложение
    string prefix = Application.StartupPath;

    return $@"{prefix}\{postfix}";
}
```

Для работы с каталогами не забывайте воспользоваться `Directory.Exists();` и если надо `Directory.CreateDirectory();`

И помните, про универсальный способ узнать путь к каталогу, в котором работает ваше приложение такой

```
string execPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

тогда для нужного вам файла, который будет лежать в подкаталоге с выполняющейся программой, можно сделать так

```
Path.Combine(execPath, @"MyDir\myFile.txt");
```

Ну, и не забывайте про ответ @Anton Bakulev про работу с спец.каталогами системы.

Answer (score 4):

Я обычно в таком случае располагаю файлы в "Моих документа"\"Название программы", собственно многие другие программы делают так же.
Получить абсолютный путь моих документов очень просто:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```